# Find file in Linux script and print its path

Tags: linux, shell

I need to find a file using shell script and print its path. And if there is no such file, print a message.
I just can't understand how to do this, 
I assume I have to use the command `find`, but I can't understand what it returns and what to do after.

Comment: Find it by what criteria? Filename, content, size, ...?

Comment: @Biffen Sorry, by filename..

Comment: Then use `find`. If you don't know how read the man page. If it's still unclear google it. When you have tried it but run into a problem ask here and be sure to include the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Note that find returns 0 as exit status when there's no result, so grep ".*"  is a hack just to return another exit status when the file is not found.

```
find "$(pwd)" -name "filename" | grep ".*"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Not Found";
fi
```

Comment: Does `find "$(pwd)"` have any advantages over `find .`?

Comment: returns the full path, and not the relative one, and i think is what he ask

Comment: Just put `|| echo "Not found"` at the end instead of the if statement.